# SharePoint Rio Linx bootstrap mobile menu will not collapse by default

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, mobile, menu

Need some help here guys and gals. Mobile menu will not collapse by default. I've noticed the asp control is not passing the CSS however it's passing it for the sidebar menu which IS closed by default. I had to target .ms-core-navigation to get the collapse/expand to work but on the first click it glitches and thinks it's already expanded so it re-animates expansion.

Here's the master page code:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse top-nav-bar">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" id="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox>ul">
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Top Menu</a>
                                </div> <!-- end navbar-header -->
                                <SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaTopNavigation" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-displayInline ms-core-navigation" role="navigation" runat="server">
                                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" ID="topNavigationDelegate">
                                        <Template_Controls>
                                            <asp:SiteMapDataSource
                                                ShowStartingNode="False"
                                                SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
                                                ID="topSiteMap"
                                                runat="server"
                                                StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002" />
                                        </Template_Controls>
                                    </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
                                        <SharePoint:AspMenu
                                            Width="100%"
                                            CssClass="collapse navbar-collapse"
                                            ID="TopNavigationMenu"
                                            runat="server"
                                            EnableViewState="false"
                                            DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
                                            AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
                                            UseSimpleRendering="true"
                                            RenderingMode="List"
                                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                                            StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                                            AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
                                            MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
                                            SkipLinkText="">
<%--                                            <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="style1" />
                                            <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="style2" />
                                            <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="style3" />
                                            <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="style4" />--%>
                                        </SharePoint:AspMenu>
                                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
                            </div> <!-- end container -->                                
                         </div> <!-- end navbar-inverse -->
```

Here's the ouput html in mobile by default:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse top-nav-bar">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" id="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox>ul">
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Top Menu</a>
                                </div> <!-- end navbar-header -->
                                <div id="DeltaTopNavigation" class="ms-displayInline ms-core-navigation" role="navigation">



    <div id="zz10_TopNavigationMenu" class="nav noindex ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox">
        <ul id="zz11_RootAspMenu" class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static">
            <li class="static selected"><a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" title="Exponent Client Site" href="/Pages/Home.aspx" accesskey="1"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Project Portal</span><span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span></span></a><ul class="static">
                <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/Pages/Project-Dashboard-Forms.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Project Dashboard</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/Pages/Reports.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Reports</span></span></a></li>
            </ul></li><li class="static ms-verticalAlignTop ms-listMenu-editLink ms-navedit-editArea"><span class="ms-navedit-editSpan" id="zz10_TopNavigationMenu_NavMenu_Edit"><a id="zz10_TopNavigationMenu_NavMenu_EditLinks" class="ms-navedit-editLinksText" href="#" onclick="g_QuickLaunchMenu = null; EnsureScriptParams('quicklaunch.js', 'QuickLaunchInitEditMode', 'zz10_TopNavigationMenu', 1, 3, 0, '\u002f'); cancelDefault(event); return false;" title="Edit Links"><span class="ms-displayInlineBlock"><span class="ms-navedit-editLinksIconWrapper ms-verticalAlignMiddle"><img class="ms-navedit-editLinksIcon" src="/_catalogs/theme/Themed/6236AB79/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=11" alt="Edit Links"></span><span class="ms-metadata ms-verticalAlignMiddle">Edit Links</span></span></a><span id="zz10_TopNavigationMenu_NavMenu_Loading" class="ms-navedit-menuLoading ms-hide"><a id="zz10_TopNavigationMenu_NavMenu_GearsLink" href="#" onclick="HideGears(); return false;" title="This animation indicates the operation is in progress. Click to remove this animated image."><img id="zz10_TopNavigationMenu_NavMenu_GearsImage" src="/_layouts/15/images/loadingcirclests16.gif?rev=40" alt="This animation indicates the operation is in progress. Click to remove this animated image."></a></span><div id="zz10_TopNavigationMenu_NavMenu_ErrorMsg" class="ms-navedit-errorMsg">

            </div></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</div>
                            </div> <!-- end container -->                                
                         </div>
```

Here's the top nav button code before it's clicked for the first time:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" id="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox>ul">
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
```

After the first click it re-animates and there is no change in the button code. Once I click it a second time to collapse it, it collapses and here is the button code:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" id="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox>ul">
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you working with?

Comment: It's SharePoint 2013 Online / Off-premise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the following code in your masterpage:

```
<div id="navBackground" class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <div id="navContainer" class="container">
            <div class="ms-dialogHidden">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~sitecollection/" CssClass="navbar-brand">Your website brand name</SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse">
                    <div class="ms-displayInline ms-core-navigation ms-dialogHidden">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
                            <PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSource ID="topSiteMap" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" SiteMapProvider="GlobalNavigationSwitchableProvider" StartFromCurrentNode="true" StartingNodeOffset="0" ShowStartingNode="false" />
                            <SharePoint:AspMenu ID="TopNavigationMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceID="topSiteMap" AccessKey="&lt;%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%&gt;" UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="1" AdjustForShowStartingNode="true" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2" SkipLinkText="" />
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then you need to modify some elements when the document's ready in JS:
I've done two JS modules for this:

```
(function (module) {
    /**
     * Make top nav conform to bootstrap
     */
    module.initializeNavBarMenu = function () {
        // Get the generated sharepoint id
        var spListMenuId = jQuery("#navBackground .ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox").attr("id");

        jQuery("#" + spListMenuId).removeClass("ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox");
        jQuery("#" + spListMenuId + ">ul").removeClass("root ms-core-listMenu-root static").addClass("nav navbar-nav");
        jQuery("#" + spListMenuId + ">ul>li.static").removeClass("static");
        // All dropdown menu
        jQuery("#" + spListMenuId + " ul>li.dynamic-children").removeClass("dynamic-children").addClass("dropdown");

        // Transform header term navigation to normal term nav
        // With Link (page, subsite, etc...)
        jQuery("#" + spListMenuId + " ul>li>a>span").replaceWith(function(){
            var elmt = jQuery(this).find("span.menu-item-text")[0];
            return elmt != null ? elmt.outerHTML : "";
        });
        // Without Link (folder)
        jQuery("#" + spListMenuId + " ul>li>span").replaceWith(function(){
            var elmt = jQuery(this).find("span.menu-item-text")[0];
            return elmt != null ? '<a href="">' + elmt.outerHTML + '</a>' : "";
        });

        jQuery("#" + spListMenuId + " ul>li.dropdown>a").removeClass().addClass("dropdown-toggle ms-core-listMenu-item").attr("aria-expanded","false").attr("aria-haspopup","true").attr("role","button").attr("data-toggle","dropdown");
        jQuery("#" + spListMenuId + " ul>li>ul").removeClass().addClass("dropdown-menu");
    }
    /**
     * Auto Hover for sub-menus
     */
    module.openOnHoverNavBarSubMenus = function () {
        // Same value of minimal width befor the transformation of menu
        // --> Show 'src/less/mixins/_mediaQuery.less' for the list of screen
        var minWidth = 768; // 768px is for tablet screen

        function toggle (event)
        {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("open");
        }

        if (jQuery( document ).width() >= minWidth)
        {
            // Remove click and tap
            jQuery('.dropdown [data-toggle=dropdown]')
                .on('click tap', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });

            jQuery('.dropdown').on('mouseenter mouseleave click tap', toggle);
        } else {
            // Add click event for bootstrap sub-menu
            jQuery('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]')
                .on('click tap', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    jQuery(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
                    jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
                });
        }
    }

    return module;
})(MyModule.Init);
```